# How to write plugin for IBM HTTP Server?

Tags: java, plugins, ibmhttpserver

How can we write plugin/module for IBM Http server? I googled but I am unable to find even a single tutorial on this. I want to start with simple "Hello world" plugin.

Also, Is it possible to write the plugin in java?

*I see IBM Http server(IHS) is based on Apache HTTP server. Does that mean IHS plugin needs to be created just like Apache modules?*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IBM HTTP Server plugins are just normal Apache HTTP Server Modules.

An example module ships in the example_module/ subdirectory of the installation.  It's quite verbose because it implements every phase of Apache processing and uses every configuration mechanism.  A hello world module.

The best resource is Nick Kew's "Apache Modules" book as well as some of the smaller modules in the httpd.apache.org source download.